# Using the softmax layer within the objective function itself

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, softmax

This is going to be long and hard to describe so apologies in advance.

I have a regular CNN like network with standard MLP layers on top of it. On top of the MLP, I have a softmax layer too, however, unlike conventional networks, this is NOT fully connected to the MLP below and it consists of subgroups.

To further describe the softmax, it looks like this:

```
Neur1A Neur2A ... NeurNA      Neur1B Neur2B ... NeurNB   Neur1C Neur2C ...NeurNC
        Group A                           Group B                Group C
```

There are many more groups. Each group has a softmax that is independent from the other groups. So it is in a way, several independent classifications (even though it actually is not).

What I need is for the index of the activated neuron to be monotonically increasing between groups. For example, if I have Neuron5 in Group A activated, I want the activated neuron in group B to be >=5.  Same with Group B and Group C and so on..

This softmax layer containing all the neurons for all groups is actually NOT my last layer and it is interestingly an intermediate one.

To achieve this monotonicity,  I add another term to my loss function that penalizes non monotonic activated neuron indices. Here is some of the code:

The code for softmax layer and its output:

```
def compute_image_estimate(layer2_input):
    estimated_yps= tf.zeros([FLAGS.batch_size,0],dtype=tf.int64)
    for pix in xrange(NUM_CLASSES):
        pixrow= int( pix/width)
        rowdata= image_pixels[:,  pixrow*width:(pixrow+1)*width]

        with tf.variable_scope('layer2_'+'_'+str(pix)) as scope:
            weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[layer2_input.get_shape()[1], width],   stddev=0.04, wd=0.0000000)
            biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [width], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
            y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(layer2_input,weights) + biases)
            argyp=width-1-tf.argmax(y,1)
            argyp= tf.reshape(argyp,[FLAGS.batch_size,1])
        estimated_yps=tf.concat(1,[estimated_yps,argyp])

        return estimated_yps
```

The estimated_yps are passed onto a function that quantifies monotonicity:

```
def compute_monotonicity(yp):
    sm= tf.zeros([FLAGS.batch_size])

    for curr_row in xrange(height):
        for curr_col in xrange(width-1):
            pix= curr_row *width + curr_col
            sm=sm+alpha * tf.to_float(tf.square(tf.minimum(0,tf.to_int32(yp[:,pix]-yp[:,pix+1]))))

    return sm
```

and the loss function is:

```
def loss(estimated_yp, SOME_OTHER_THINGS):
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', SOME_OTHER_THINGS)

    monotonicity_metric= tf.reduce_mean( compute_monotonocity(estimated_yp) )
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', monotonicity_metric)
    return tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')
```

Now my problem is, when I do not use SOME_OTHER_THINGS that are conventional metrics,  I get `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable` for the monotonocity metric.

Seems like gradients are not defined when the softmax layer outputs are used like this.

Am I doing something wrong?   Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies.. I realized that the problem is that tf.argmax function obviously does not have a gradient defined.